# Can docker service replace docker run?

Tags: docker-swarm

I'm converting my Docker hosts into Docker Swarm Nodes. Before this I always ran Docker hosts/containers moreorless like a [vSAN-less] vSphere cluster with as little storage as possible per host centralizing it instead. Never run anything on the bridge network, only use dedicated addresses or the host's network and avoid compose files so I don't have to remember where they are or lose them with a failed host. I keep a single file of all the detailed `docker run`s commands (preceded with docker `..stop X` & `..rm X` for conflict prevention). The contents of the file can be copied and pasted or run as a script and containers are restored regardless where they're run. Even the *macvlans* are recreated.

A second script sets up network mounts so paths are identical and cron jobs to sync certs (for symlinking) with a central server that requests them. Basically it was already clustered minus the automatic placement of containers. I'm "formally clustering" to gain that ability. I don't need dynamic workload balancing or anything fancier that just being able to view all hosts in a single pane of glass so Swarm is perfect but I'm not sure how to transform my "docker runs" properly.

Is the `docker service` command a replacement for `docker run`? The examples in the documentation are extremely generic in details, the whole thing is very vague when it comes to swarm mode.

Also, what I think the equivalent options it has, introduce ambiguity. For instance, `--volume` isn't there but there's `--mount`. When I think of "volume" it's storage on a disk/array that's immediate to the system managing it, when I think or "mount"…sure, it can be local but with a bias to removable storage but really it's network mounts what comes to mind. The description doesn't clarify anything though, or if it is abstracted too or made as needed from a node to storage or what. Same for `--network`, can I choose one of the existing `macvlan` networks I used before or new networks are created on-the-fly or need to be created?

Thanks!

Comment: So you keep one central file but you're afraid you might lose a compose file? Sounds weird. It really sounds like you have some reading to do. For instance `mount` and `volume` are already distinct with `docker run`. They can share some aspect but are already different. I don't see how it's very generic when the [documentation on `docker service create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#add-bind-mounts-volumes-or-memory-filesystems) even points out the (some of) difference between mount and volume.

Comment: That central file is synced across several systems. It's unlikely to get lost. I've been researching and it seems that there are petitions for containers to supports static addresses since 2016 so I changed course and deployed vSphere Integrated Containers instead. Works very similar and with a nice UI. Also available standalone (and open source) as VMware Admiral. Thanks anyway!